# Find constants from probability density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to determine two constants $a$ and $b$ such that $p( \phi )$ satisfy the conditions for a probability density and that $p(\pi )=p(-\pi )=0$.

I have that $p( \phi ) = a\cdot\cos(b\cdot \phi)$

I know that the function must integrates to one and the function is non-negative everywhere. But how can I use that to find $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Unless you restrict $\phi$ to a subinterval, $p$ will never be a probability density, since $p\left(\frac\pi b\right) = -a$ and $p(0)=a$, and $a$ cannot be both positive and negative at the same time.

Comment: Sorry should have added that ϕ is in the interval [-$/pi, /pi$]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. I guess that the domain of definition of $p$ is the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. 
Then $p(\pi )=p(-\pi )=0$ imply that $b=1/2$. Moreover $a$ is the positive real number such that
$$1=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}p(\phi) d\phi=2a\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(\phi/2) d\phi.$$
Are you able to find $a$?

Comment: Solving the equation I get *a=1/4*. Is this correct?

Comment: @ToyMan Yes. I got the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just wanted to know if *a* were correct before I "accepted" the answer :) would have given you +rep, but dont have enough rep myself to do that :(

Comment: @ToyMan It's fine. Happy to be useful!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

1. What is the value of $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi a\cos(b\cdot\phi)d\phi?$$

To calculate this integral, introduce a new variable $\tau = b\cdot \phi$.

2. What's the value of $p(\pi)$?

---

Each of the points above gives you one equation that $a$ and $b$ must satisfy.